# Menu divider image drops too low

Tags: css

Have a look at the home icon on the top left hand side of this page:

http://newslines.org/newslines-rewards/

You will see a little orange line drop below orange header to the bottom left of the home button. I have been trying for hours to move it up the few pixels necessary. Any help most appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `padding top` and `bottom` valu and make `height` as `38px`

```
#top-navigation .top-menu-left li a {
cursor: pointer;
padding: 0px 20px;
display: inline-block;
height: 38px;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: That works, but it breaks the position of the "About" text in the next block.